# Как убрать index.php из ссылки?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Как превратить с помощью `.htaccess` ссылку типа `"example.com/index.php?lang=en"` в `"example.com/en"`?

Comment: @Vlad Spirin А здесь метка PHP не лишняя ли?

Comment: @0xdb Никак нет. Нужна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]+)$ index.php?lang=$1
```

p.s регулярку только можете упростить, если не планируете передавать туда заглавные буквы и цифры.

Comment: Спасибо вам, ваш вариант тоже рабочий!)
Но уже воспользовался ответом выше))